# Plain Text Query Logs

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for a way to get plain text query logs out of SQL Server. I want the output to be similar to what the profiler provides, just to a plain text file.

SSMS and the profiler aren't suitable because I want the results to be usable in the terminal for later manipulation with command line tools.

Ideally the format would be configurable, but as long as it's somewhat structured I want profiler like output streamed to a plain text log file like:

```
SQL:BatchCompleted  MyApp  MyLogin  Database1
select * from foo
SQL:BatchCompleted  OtherApp  OtherLogin  Database2
select * from foo
```

Comment: No idea what this means. I suggest you post an example of what information you seek inside the database engine and the format you expect in your file.

Comment: I added an example. I want information similar to the SSMS Profiler, just logged to plain text file, not fussy about the format.

Comment: Use [Extended events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Does that output plain text? Maybe it's just an encoding issue, but opening the file in vim or notepad looks like .xel files are a binary format.